How to pack multiple int8 data into a string that can be a initializer for C++ variable?
I want to use python to convert a int8 numpy array to a string that can be a included as intializer for my C++ array defined like uint32 arr[]={packed_int8_data, ...}. Notice that uint32 is just a data container and I want to split it into multiple C++ int8 variables later.
I write python code like this to pack 4 int8 data into a datapack, but when I decode it, the sign is missing. I'm really confused about the Two's complement representation, so what is the problem and how to fix it?
import numpy as np
def pack_int8_to_uint32(int8_values):
    uint32_data = 0
    for i, value in enumerate(int8_values):
        uint32_data |= (value & 0xFF) << (8 * i)
    
    return uint32_data

int8_values = np.array([-10, -16, 15, 8], dtype=np.int8).tolist()

packed_uint32 = pack_int8_to_uint32(int8_values)

def unpack_uint32_to_int8(uint32_data):
    int8_values = []
    for i in range(4):
        int8_values.append((uint32_data >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF)
    return int8_values

unpacked_int8_values = unpack_uint32_to_int8(packed_uint32)

print("Unpacked int8 values:", unpacked_int8_values)

print(hex(packed_uint32))

result
Unpacked int8 values: [246, 240, 15, 8]
0x80ff0f6

And I want to print the packed data into string so I can use it like initializer like this:uint32 data = 0x80ff0f6

The signs for -10 (0xF6) and -16 (0xF0) are still there. What exactly are you trying to do here?

You should not use a loop for that. What you want seems just hex(v.view(np.uint32)[0]), isn't it? It is dependent of the machine endianness but the C++ code might be too. You can swap bytes if needed by detecting the endianess or just use the struct module made exactly for such operations. The same strategy can be used for the reverse operation with np.view(np.int8). Note that signed/unsigned conversion is machine dependent (C2 on most machines but old machine or embedded ones can use C1). AFAIK C++ standarized that recently but not C (so not in Numpy).

Because python integers have unlimited precision it treats each 8-bit value as a positive integer. You can restore the original signs with this modified version of your unpack function:
def unpack_uint32_to_int8(uint32_data):
    int8_values = []
    for i in range(4):
        num = uint32_data >> (8 * i) & 0xFF
        if num & 0x80:             # if the sign bit is set
            num = ~(num ^ 0xFF)    # restore the original signed value
        int8_values.append(num)
    return int8_values

